# How can an iPhone file browser see my apps files, and how can I stop it

Tags: ios, cocoa

I understand that on a non jail broken device an iPhone app is sandboxed.  I thought this meant that its files would be hidden.  How is it then that an application such as iExplorer ( http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/ ) can see my apps files ?  And is there a way to prevent this ?

Comment: Now no need to worry, use iOS8.3 n above. [Stop iTunes File Sharing](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/04/13/ios-8-3-ifunbox-itools-sandbox-app-access/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandboxing only means that your app can't access any files outside of it's "sandbox", hence your app can't access other apps' files, but your app's files aren't hidden.

There's no way you can prevent this. If you have sensitive data that you store on the device, you'll need to encrypt it.

**Update:**
If you need to protect a custom font or something similar, you should take a look at this guide about encrypting resource files: http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/

Comment: I am using encryption for certain files - but some such as those generated by a UIWebView under ~/Library/caches are more problematic to encrypt as I don't have 100 % control on when they might be accessed. Is there no other way to protect them ?

Comment: It'd be useful to know what you're trying to protect. There's not much you can do when WebKit stores those files for you, but caches shouldn't contain sensitive data in the first place. There is a way to protect certain files (such as custom fonts you might be using in the web view). Have a look at this blog post: http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/

Comment: Specifically I wish to protect the files generated by HTML5 database

Comment: You'll need to find a different way so that the database doesn't contain sensitive user data, sorry.